# iOS: UIBackgroundFetch - PerformFetch not called

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to update my app in background, so I added Required background modes "fetch" to my info.plist.
In my FinishedLaunching I added:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval (UIApplication.BackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum);
```

And overwriting the method PerformFetch:

```
public override void PerformFetch (UIApplication application, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("PerformFetch called...");

//Return no new data by default
var result = UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData;
...

completionHandler (result);
}
```

But the method never get called... :(

What's the problem, I can't find any mistakes? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, system solves itself when call this handler, it's unpredictable event. 
And you never determine  a certain time of execution.
Lately, I investigated it and really got upset.
Early, simulator allowed to simulate a call directly.

Comment: yes, it was fine, I could catch event, but i couldn't determine exact time, the handler happens occasionally.

Comment: If you can "catch" the event with a breakpoint, try typing `bt` from the `LLDB` prompt. That is backtrace, which will show you what happened immediately before the breakpoint. It might give you some color re: where your problem lives.

Comment: Thank  you for tip, i appreciate it.And what further? I mean how to determine a principle of call by time

Comment: I tried it with a breakpoint two, but I think I waited to short. I will test it with the simulator. The problem is that apple told me, sorry but we don't want a update/sync button in app, please remove it and run update in background! Ok now I will run the update automatically at the first start of the app and keep the app up to date with background updates.

Comment: ...but why UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval (10); not working. If I understood, the handler should be called every 10 seconds?

Comment: NO, It means how much time this scope of function will be executed. You can't hold on too long your execution in background mode of your app. I misunderstood your problem about. Did you mean that your app was rejected by reason of updating buttons ?

Comment: Yes the app was rejected because of the synchronize button in my app. Apple said it could confuse the user and I should use the background update and remove the sync button. My idea was to give the user decision to update the content. :-|

Comment: Try to dig off a NSUrlSession class, there are methods working in background mode, but I'm not sure that it's the same case regarding to your problem, because NSUrlSession works with downloading and uploading data, possibly may embed your execution in them handlers

Comment: I tried the background fetch with the simulator and it worked as expected. But the fetch never called on the device. (waited hours)  :/

Comment: Same here. PerformFetch took almost 24h when I debugged it the first time. Since this is unbelievably long, I fire a local notification (of course only on dev versions of my app) whenever the PerformFetch method is called.

Answer (score 2):

On an iOS device, this method is called unpredictably by the OS. There are many factors that go into how often this method is called, including how you've configured the interval and how much time your app usually takes to perform background fetches. If you routinely take a long time to perform a fetch, the OS will call this method less often. See the section "Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically" here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

and the API reference here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:

If you are testing your app in the simulator, you can simulate a background fetch from the Xamarin Studio menu with Run -> Simulate iOS Background Fetch. If you need to initiate downloads reliably based on some external event, consider using push notifications with the "content-available" flag set. See the section "Using Push Notifications to Initiate a Download" from the first link.

Comment: Does not answer the question at all. It clearly states that `PerformFetch` _never_ gets called.